# Что не так с GRUB?

Tags: linux, grub, kali-linux

Установил Kali Linux как вторую ОС на внешний вин. Всё работает ок, но вот с GRUB проблемы...

Когда просто нажимаю кнопку включения, ноут запускается и выдаёт такую ерунду

[image: ОШИБКА GRUB]

Если же я запущу GRUB через Boot Menu, то всё будет ок. Что с этим делать?

Comment: Изменить настройки bios так, чтобы по умолчанию загружался GRUB, а не загрузчик винды? =) (ну  или не винды, не знаю какая вторая ОС)

Comment: @Inventor, так по-умолчанию загружается GRUB. Просто он ищет какую-то флешку. А если запустить через Boot Menu, то он всё находит

Comment: Была похожая проблема с ubuntu. Мне помогло это: https://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_grub

Comment: @invertor, не помогло, теперь переустанавливаю всю ос XD

Comment: Используйте `systemd-boot`

Comment: Понял что проблема в винчестере. Он у меня внешний и запускается позже чем GRUB, из-за этого GRUB считает что его нету и выдаёт такую ерунду

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Короче говоря, мой винчестер запускается медленее чем GRUB, из-за того что он старый. Проблему решил установкой rEFInd

Answer (score -1):

Во-первых, Kali использовать как вторую ОС - торжество разума, впрочем дело ваше

Во-вторых, белым по чёрному написано, что grub ищет девайс с uuid `d286..` и судя по всему не находит

Выставите правильный first boot девайс и пробуйте `sudo update-grub`

А вообще, не очень понятны ваши формулировки, `"он ищет какую-то флешку. А если запустить через Boot Menu, то он всё находит"`. Да и вывод `sudo fdisk -l` не помешал бы

Comment: *Kali использовать как вторую ОС - торжество разума* - почему?

Comment: Вывод `sudo fdisk -l` будет позже, сейчас всю ОС переустанавливаю.

Comment: First boot девайс стоит верный

Comment: @dIm0n, потому что её надо оставлять единственную на железе!

Comment: @0andriy почему?

Comment: @dIm0n, потому что сарказм.

Comment: В общем вот официальный док с сайта kali про дуалбут с виндой https://www.kali.org/docs/installation/kali-linux-dual-boot-kali-with-windows/

Comment: @dIm0n потому что Kali линукс это не дистрибутив для тех, что не может груб завести или ядро пересобрать. Но люди упорно его ставят, думая, что он с них сделает крутых хацкеров.

Comment: @KoVadim а причём тут установка второй системой?

Comment: установка второй системы в паралель == настройка груба (или другого менеджера).